# MysQL SELECT statement if empty

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am struggling a bit with something that I think should be simple to solve.

I first check the database to see if it exists.  I would like it to insert the date if it does not exist but I am not sure how to structure the IF statement part.  Many thanks

```
$date='2017-05-13';
$select_date = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from `marker` WHERE `date`='$date' ");

$insert_date = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `marker` (`date`,`value`) VALUES ('$date','1') ");
```

Comment: Check for the number of rows returned after your first query, if that is 0, run the insert

Comment: Use mysql [ON DUPLICATE KEY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax

Comment: SO is not really a tutorial site. There are plenty of sites out theere for that.

Comment: The dup target gives PDO code instead of mysqli. If you are just starting to learn, switch to PDO.

Comment: secondly as explained in that answer don't do SELECT followed up insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for this type of operation, you want to use `on duplicate key update`.  This starts with a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_marker_date ON marker(date);
```

Then the database guarantees only one row per date.  You can then do the insert as:

```
INSERT INTO `marker` (`date`, `value`)
    VALUES ('$date', '1')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `date` = VALUES(`date`);
```

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` part does nothing except prevent an error for a duplicate date.

Comment: Thanks i've implemented this and it works as required.  It is a shame that my question has been down voted because the others thought it was too simple.  Thanks again for this code!